# Error in addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url) : addResourcePath called with invalid prefix; please see documentation

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I'm an inexperienced programmer that is completely new to Shiny. For transparency, I am doing this as part of a school assignment, but also want to really learn how to use ShinyApps and data visualization tools. Any assistance would be appreciated.

**Server.R** - For this one, I start to receive errors when I begin the render plots. When I look at other examples of code for time series plots, there is a string($) that follows output.  I am not sure if that works with my plots. I also think there is an issue with 'plot_impact_by_year'.  Again, I don't know if I should be referencing something else or nothing at all.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rCharts)

# Load data 
dt <- read.csv("NBAdata.csv", header=TRUE)

# Shiny server 
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {      
})

# Prepare datasets
        # Prepare for time series
        dt.agg.year <- reactive({
                aggregate_by_year(dt, input$range[1], input$range[2])
        })

# Render Plots
        # 3-Pointers by Year
        output <- renderChart({
                plot_impact_by_year(
                        dt = dt.agg.year() %>% select(Year, 3PM, 3PA),
                        yAxisLabel = "3-Pointers Per Game",
                        desc = TRUE
                )
        })

        # Fouls versus Pace and Points by Year
        output <- renderChart({
                plot_impact_by_year(
                        dt = dt.agg.year() %>% select(Year, PF, Pace, Pts),
                        yAxisLabel = "Per Game Statistics",
                        desc = TRUE
                )
        })
```

**ui.R** - When I run the code individually, I receive the following error when I enter the very last closed parentheses:

Error in addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url) : 
  addResourcePath called with invalid prefix; please see documentation

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

# Load the dataset
dt <- read.csv("NBAdata.csv", header=TRUE)

shinyUI(
        navbarPage("3-Pointers and Pace of Play in the NBA",
                   tabPanel("Plot",
                            sidebarPanel(
                                    sliderInput("Year", "Year:", 
                                                min = 1979, max = 2015, value = c(1995, 2015),
                            ),

                            mainPanel(
                                    tabsetPanel(

                                            # Time series data
                                            tabPanel(p(icon("line-chart"), "By year"),
                                                     h4('Number of 3-pointers by year', align = "center"),
                                                     showOutput("3PM", "3PA")),

                                            tabPanel(p(icon("line-chart"), "By year"),
                                                     h4('Fouls versus Pace and Points by year', align = "center"),
                                                     showOutput("PF", "Pace", "Pts")),    
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```